# Sigsuspend equivalent to atomic series of sigprocmask, pause, sigprocmask?

Tags: c, exception, signals, signal-handling, multiple-processes

I was reading my textbook's chapter (CS:APP, 3rd ed., chapter 8, page 781) on signals/ECF for Linux x86-64 systems, and came across this:

> The sigsuspend function temporarily replaces the current blocked set with mask and then suspends the process until the receipt of a signal whose action is either to run a handler or to terminate the process. If the action is to terminate, then the process terminates without returning from sigsuspend. If the action is to run a handler, then sigsuspend returns after the handler returns, restoring the blocked set to its state when sigsuspend was called.
>
> The sigsuspend function is equivalent to an atomic (uninterruptible) version of the following:
>
> ```
> 1       sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, &mask, &prev);
> 2       pause();
> 3       sigprocmask(SIG_SETMASK, &prev, NULL);
> ```

As I understand it, `sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, &mask, &prev)` should result in the blocked set being OR-ed with mask, i.e. adding the signals in mask to those already in the blocked set. But the text directly above the code (and the man-page for sigsuspend, which I looked up) says that sigsuspend "temporarily *replaces* the current blocked set with mask". That sounds more like `sigprocmask(SIG_SETMASK, &mask, &prev)` to me, where the blocked set is just set equal to the signals in the mask.

So why is `sigsuspend(&mask)` equivalent to the code above (lines 1-3) and not the code below (lines 4-6)? Where did I go wrong in my intuition and/or understanding of signal.h functions?

```
4       sigprocmask(SIG_SETMASK, &mask, &prev);
5       pause();
6       sigprocmask(SIG_SETMASK, &prev, NULL);
```

If I'm not being clear, let me ask a concrete question instead (it might explain my intuition better). Say the current blocked set encodes SIGCHLD, and the sigset_t mask encodes SIGINT. I call `sigsuspend(&mask)`. No matter which code interpretation is right (lines 1-3 OR 4-6), a SIGINT signal delivered just after the call to sigsuspend would  be blocked/not wake up the process. However, what if right after the call to sigsuspend, a SIGCHLD signal is delivered? Will the process wake up/receive the signal? My intuition says lines 1-3 would block a SIGCHLD while lines 4-6 wouldn't, so clearly lines 1-3 and 4-6 aren't equivalent. But my intuition also says that sigsuspend shouldn't block SIGCHLD because it's not in mask, so lines 4-6 are correct, and if lines 4-6 are equivalent to sigsuspend in this case, sigsuspend can't be equivalent to lines 1-3. Where did my intuition/understanding go wrong?

Comment: Well, I feel kind of stupid now. I'm not used to textbooks being wrong, I never would have thought to look for corrections made to the book. I'll check that in the future. Thanks!

Comment: Helpful hint: If your professor is the author of this textbook, broach this subject *very delicately*, or not at all.

Comment: You might want to accept Mark's answer below?

Answer (score 4):

The thing about technical books (and textbooks in particular) is that you should always be aware of whether or not there is *errata* available.

This [link](http://csapp.cs.cmu.edu/3e/errata.html) for the errata for that book shows:

> Chapter 8: Exceptional Control Flow
>   ...
>   ...
>   p. 781. In the description of `sigsuspend` in the second paragraph, line 1 should be:
>   `sigprocmask(SIG_SETMASK, &mask, &prev);`
>   Posted 10/28/2015. Dave O'Hallaron